# LINQ returning Null while same query when write in SQL return result

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have two tables `Survey_Response` and `Questions`.

Columns in `Survey_Response` are:

```
ID PK
SurveyID FK
QuestionID FK
Response varchar
FilledBy FK
```

Columns in `Questions` are:

```
ID PK
Text varchar
QuestionType varchar
Options varchar
```

SQL Server query that is working fine:

```
select * 
from Survey_Response SR
inner join Questions q on SR.QuestionID = q.ID
where SR.SurveyID='1008'
```

LINQ that is returning null value is,

```
    ResponseList = (from r in ObjectSur.Survey_Response
                    join q in ObjectSur.Questions on r.SurveyID equals q.ID
                    where r.SurveyID.Equals(prefix)
                    select new ResponseViewModel
                    {
                        QuestionID = r.QuestionID,
                        Text = q.Text,
                        Response = r.Response,
                        FilledBy = r.FilledBy
                    }).ToList();
```

I think both queries are same.

Hoping for your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: it returns null or empty list? `prefix` is the same as in working query?

Comment: Plus you join on `QuestionID` in SQL then `SurveyID` in linq

Comment: Showing "ResponseList count 0" and prefix is same value

Comment: :/ i am a blind man !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both queries are not the same as you *join* on `QuestionID` in SQL then `SurveyID` in Linq

```
ResponseList = (from r in ObjectSur.Survey_Response
                join q in ObjectSur.Questions on r.QuestionID equals q.ID //<-- change here
                where r.SurveyID.Equals(prefix)
                select new ResponseViewModel
                {
                    QuestionID = r.QuestionID,
                    Text = q.Text,
                    Response = r.Response,
                    FilledBy = r.FilledBy
                }).ToList();
```